# I can not use query in dynamoose becasue error: 'Index can't be found for query.'

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, dynamoose

I'm using nest JS 9 which are using dynamoDB and dynamoose.
I found a library which can support me connect to db **nestjs-dynamoose**
i tried to write a get many API but a got Error at **.exec()**

```
const pagination = formatPagination(basePagination);
    const query = this.baseRepo
      .query()
      .limit(+pagination.limit);
      .sort(pagination.sort);
    if (pagination.page > 1) {
      query.startAt(basePagination.keyItem);
    }
    const result = await query
      .exec()
      .then((result) => result)
      .catch((err) => err);
    return result;
```

here is my schema

```
schema: new Schema(
    {
      id: {
        type: Number,
        rangeKey: true,
      },

      songCode: {
        type: String,
        index: {
          name: 'songCodeIndex',
        },
      },

      music: {
        type: String,
        hashKey: true,
        index: {
          name: 'musicIndex',
          rangeKey: 'id',
        },
      },
  // ..... another field
    },
    {
      timestamps: defaultSettings,
    },
  )
```

I replaced **Query** with **Scan.** It worked, but the scan command did not support sort options.
I tried to follow the GPT solution, but it seemed to not work.
I checked in the noSQL workbench and saw 2 GSIs in the table.

Please help me. I'm stucking more than 4 hours at this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Query, you must always pass in the partition key value. And if you want to Query from one of your indices you must explicitly state so:

```
const query = this.baseRepo
      .query("music").eq("some-music")
      .using("musicIndex")
```

I suggest you thoroughly read the Dynamoose Docs on [Query](https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Query)

Comment: I read the docs. But i have a question
the docs have some example but i saw that they don't need to use .using().
Can you help to me explain why they no need to do that?

Comment: If you read from your base table you do not need to use `using()`